what is the gnome setting schema for screencast?
So far I cannot find anyway to config the org.gnome.Shell.Screencast or org.gnome.Screencast
gsettings list-schemas does not show any related entry.
Is there any configuration option get exposed at all?
ubuntu 22.04 and ubuntu 24.04

Different versions of Ubuntu use different versions of Gnome. You need to edit the question and enter the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please use the edit feature and not add the info as a comment.

why does there need to be one? lots of software use a native XML
